# Usage of "dare"

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

In German, when you are about to introduce someone, you say:

> Darf ich vorstellen ...?

which literally means, ***dare** I introduce ...?*

However, *dare* is [becoming extinct](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dare&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) recently.

So, my question is, **is it grammatical to use *dare* in a modern language**, contrary to *may*?

Comment: In most senses *dürfen* should be translated with *may*, in the sense of *be permitted to*, rather than *dare*. And *dare* is hardly becoming “extinct”; what you are seeing in the NGram is rather a proliferation of printed sources of kinds in which *dare* is not called for. *May*, on the other hand, is declining, like all full modals; in the *dürfen* sense it has colloquially been replaced by *can*, while *can* in its basic sense is often replaced by the semi-modal *be able to*.

Comment: As StoneyB implies, your NGram doesn't tell us much about actual usage patterns. For example, if you look at [how dare he](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+dare+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) the chart suggests this usage has in fact become much *more* popular in recent decades.

Comment: I guess if the act of introducing someone *is* risky, say, you want to introduce your stoner friend to your corporate CEO, then you might ponder: "Dare I introduce him...?" but that's definitely not the same usage pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an example of using dare, you can say:

> "I dare say that you are rich because of the way you dress."

It is a way to soften what otherwise might be a harsh judgment.

Or

> "I dare you to...

It means tempting someone.

But for an introduction, "dare" is not used. Use may:

> May I introduce you..."

Answer (score 4):

As verb, *dare* is used to mean:

- Have the courage of doing something
- Challenge somebody to do something
- Take the risk of

It is never used when introducing somebody to someone else, for which *may* is normally used.